# How can we emit and consume an event in nodejs , just a POC

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to know how can we emit and consume an event in nodejs. As I amm new to Nodejs... Want to do a POC around it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?
https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/the-nodejs-event-emitter/

This page describes EventEmitter class and answers your question exactly. You can specify event listeners with `.on()` function and emit events with `.emit()` function. Please provide more details if this does not answer your question.